# Include package data when installing

Tags: python, resources, packaging

I have a problem when trying to install a Python package that I have created.
The package includes a bitmap images which is used within the package (for OCR).

My folder structure is the following:

```
mypackage
  - mypackage
     - media
        - template.bmp
  - module1.py
  - module2.py
  - etc...
- tests
- MANIFEST.in
- setup.py
```

template.bmp is used by the module1.py.

The MANIFEST.in file:

```
include mypackage/media/template.bmp
```

The setup.py:

```
setup(
    ....
    packages = find_packages(exclude=["*.tests", "*.tests.*", "tests.*", "tests"]),
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={'mypackage': ['media/template.bmp']},
    ...
)
```

When I run

```
python setup.py sdist
```

I can verify that the media folder is included along with template.bmp in the .egg file. However, when referencing the bitmap in a module using

```
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
template_path = directory + '/media/template.bmp'
cv2.imread(template_path, 0)
```

I get a file not found error. The directory variable is the following:

```
'C:\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\mypackage-0.0.1-py3.6.egg\\mypackage'
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Using pkg_resources solved my problem.

```
template_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, '/media/template.bmp')
```